# Does H2 database support configure condition of @Where clouse

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, integration-testing, h2

I'm using MySql for development mode and h2 in memory database for integration testing. Below My Configuration:

***src\test\resources\application.yaml***

```
spring:
  datasource:
    primary:
      url: jdbc:h2:mem:app;MODE=MySQL;
      driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
      username: __username
      password: __password
  jpa:
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
      naming:
        implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
        globally_quoted_identifiers: true
        globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions: true
```

***AggregationService.kt***

```
    fun getAggregations(widgetFieldContentId: Int?): ResponseEntity<ResponseGetAggregations> {
        val aggregation = widgetFieldContentId?.let {
            widgetFieldContentRepository findOutById it
        }?.aggregation
        val data = Aggregation
            .values()
            .filter { aggregation == null || (it.value and aggregation) != ZERO }
            .map(mapper::toDTO)
        return responseOK(data)
    }
```

***AggregationServiceIntegrationTest.kt***

```
@Test
@DisplayName("AggregationService_getAggregationsWithWidgetFieldContentId_shouldRequestToDatabase_returnsAvailableAggregationsForWidgetFieldContent")
    fun getAggregationsWitWidgetFieldContentId() {
        // Arrange
        val widgetFieldContentId = 1

        // Act & Assert
        val response = assertDoesNotThrow { service.getAggregations(widgetFieldContentId) }

        // Assert
        assertAll(
            { assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.statusCode) },
            { assertNotNull(response.body?.data) },
            { response.body?.success?.let(::assertTrue) },
            { response.body?.data?.isNotEmpty()?.let(::assertTrue) }
        )

    }
```

After creating tables without an exception ***getAggregationsWitWidgetFieldContentId*** function requests to db with condition of enabled=true which indicated @Where annotation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "widget_field_content", uniqueConstraints = [UniqueConstraint(columnNames = ["name", "category_id"])])
@Where(clause = "enabled=true")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE widget_field_content SET enabled=FALSE WHERE id=? AND enabled")
class WidgetFieldContentEntity(

    @Column(
        nullable = false,
        columnDefinition = "JSON"
    )
    val name: String,
...
```

And for that condition application throws an exception:
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "WIDGETFIEL0_.ENABLED" not found; SQL statement:
select widgetfiel0_."id" as id1_8_0_, widgetfiel0_."auditor_id" as auditor11_8_0_, widgetfiel0_."enabled" as enabled2_8_0_, widgetfiel0_."aggregation" as aggregat3_8_0_, widgetfiel0_."category_id" as categor12_8_0_, widgetfiel0_."filter_id" as filter_13_8_0_, widgetfiel0_."filterCondition" as filterco4_8_0_, widgetfiel0_."filterType" as filterty5_8_0_, widgetfiel0_."filterValue" as filterva6_8_0_, widgetfiel0_."name" as name7_8_0_, widgetfiel0_."outValue" as outvalue8_8_0_, widgetfiel0_."selectValue" as selectva9_8_0_, widgetfiel0_."sortValue" as sortval10_8_0_, widgetfiel1_."id" as id1_9_1_, widgetfiel1_."auditor_id" as auditor_8_9_1_, widgetfiel1_."enabled" as enabled2_9_1_, widgetfiel1_."max" as max3_9_1_, widgetfiel1_."measurement" as measurem4_9_1_, widgetfiel1_."min" as min5_9_1_, widgetfiel1_."multipleOption" as multiple6_9_1_, widgetfiel1_."optionUrl" as optionur7_9_1_ from "widget_field_content" widgetfiel0_ left outer join "widget_field_content_filter" widgetfiel1_ on widgetfiel0_."filter_id"=widgetfiel1_."id" where widgetfiel0_."id"=? and ( widgetfiel0_.enabled=true) [42122-214]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.getColumnException(ExpressionColumn.java:244) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.optimizeOther(ExpressionColumn.java:226) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.optimize(ExpressionColumn.java:213) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at org.h2.expression.condition.Comparison.optimize(Comparison.java:139) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at org.h2.expression.condition.ConditionAndOr.optimize(ConditionAndOr.java:137) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at org.h2.expression.Expression.optimizeCondition(Expression.java:148) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at org.h2.command.query.Select.prepareExpressions(Select.java:1177) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at org.h2.command.query.Query.prepare(Query.java:218) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:575) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:92) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
147 more

Can anyone solve it?

I'm traying to configure condition like configured table creation with

```
      naming:
        implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```